# perforce filespec regex format

Tags: perforce

I am trying to restrict a user from being able to write to .c files in a depot location. I found 2 ways to achieve this. Add

`=write growth * -//depot/new_team/....c`

or

`=write growth * -//depot/new_team/.../*.c`

to protect table. Are both of these correct? Does one have preference over other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very similar but not identical.

```
//depot/new_team/....c
```

This selects all files that end in `.c` anywhere under `//depot/new_team/`. For example, it matches `//depot/new_team/foo.c` as well as `//depot/new_team/dir/foo.c`.

```
//depot/new_team/.../*.c
```

This selects all files that end in `.c` in **subdirectories** of `//depot/new_team/`. It matches `//depot/new_team/dir/foo.c` but not `//depot/new_team/foo.c`. In the case of `//depot/new_team/foo.c`, it is not a match because your pattern asks for a slash between `...` and `*.c`, but `//depot/new_team/foo.c` doesn't have one.